# Query to return the distinct first characters for given text column

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have a contacts db - name, phone number, etc. I want to run a query where the result set would be first letters (unique) of the `name` column in ASC/DESC order. That is suppose my table looked like this:

```
name                           phone number
-------------------------------------------
Alice                          xxx
Mitch                          xxx
Eric                           xxx
Eric                           xxx
```

The result set would have three rows - `A`, `E` & `M`. Then when I need to fetch names beginning with `A` I would run another query.

A pseudo query might look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    firstCharFrom(`name`) AS indexChar 
FROM 
    'myTable` 
ORDER BY
    indexChar;
```

I welcome any commentary on the performance of this query against the simple:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY `name`
```

where the client takes cake of grouping the result set into buckets `(A, E, M)` himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) AS indexChar
FROM myTable
ORDER BY indexChar
```

You can find a list of all SQLite functions at [Core Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Comment: Would this work for unicode text? I am wondering if this logic will correctly sort Japanese, Korean, Chinese etc. The docs you pointed to does specify that the text is UTF8.

Comment: I have no idea, try it and see.